# Why do I not have to declare a "new" object sometimes in Java?

Tags: java

Apologies for what is probably an easy question. I cannot find anything straight forward to answer this one. In the following code, why am I not required to create a "new" object? What exactly am I assigning sequencer to?

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MusicTest1 {

    public void play() {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

        System.out.println("We got a sequencer");
    } // close play

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MusicTest1 mt = new MusicTest1();
        mt.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had a similar question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223471/why-do-c-and-java-both-use-the-notion-of-reference-but-not-in-the-same-sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to `Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();`, you are calling a static method of the class `MidiSystem` that returns an instance of `Sequencer`. The static method does the `new Sequencer()` for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getSequencer` makes a new object and returns it. It probably returns the same object if it has already created one. This is called the singleton pattern.

Comment: Well, without seeing the code of that method you can't know for sure it's the Singleton pattern (could be Factory), but based on the class names it makes sense.

Comment: They would have called Factory something like .newSequencer() or maybe .defaultSequencer()..

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.java#MidiSystem.getSequencer%28%29